# How can you sign with Metamask without web3?

Tags: web3js, metamask

The latest Metamask versions completely remove `web3`. Even if you pull `web3` in from the CDN package, Metamask will throw an error when you try to use it.

All answers I have seen for signing had used `web3` to use sign, including [How to verify MetaMask account holder is the real owner of the address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/how-to-verify-metamask-account-holder-is-the-real-owner-of-the-address). As noted there, `web3` is no longer allowed. Even the [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask) are out of date. They point to https://danfinlay.github.io/js-eth-personal-sign-examples/, which has the error I speak of when you click `eth_sign`.

[image: image showing web3 no longer used]

I tried the following:

```js
// address is returned from eth_requestAccounts
const promise = await ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_sign',
  params: [address, `Please sign to verify you own ${address}`],
})
```

I'm aware I need to do some kind of encryption for the message, but not sure what to do there. Aside from that, I get a nasty warning from Metamask about this method and when I click "Sign" the promise never resolves. The kicker is that the Learn More link takes me to a page that I can't access, even when signed into their Zendesk:  https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015488751

[image: error that says current method is dangerous and deprecated]

When I go to https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#sign-typed-data-v4, I see there is supposedly a better method of `signTypedData_v4`. It links to a [blog post](https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26) about it, but it references deprecated methods, still says `_v3` in the post, and is using version 4 of Metamask while the current is up to 10. When I even try `signTypedData_v4`, it says that is not a supported method from Metamask.

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: for now you just copy pasted some image out of somewhere(you didn't see it yourself).

Comment: The images are all things I saw. I am unable to get the promise resolved from `ethereum.request`. My post says "I get a nasty warning from Metamask about this method and when I click "Sign" the promise never resolves."

Comment: https://github.com/alexeyneu/onboard/blob/0e8286e1b6b62077790b0530dc11328d7e26bf92/src/Onboard/BoardForm.jsx#L45

Comment: just tested it - yeah connection doesn't work anymore. haha     so for now i can't check sign

Comment: for this kind of stuff i've dealt with nifty wallet instead

Comment: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So most answers on Stack say to use `web3.eth.personal.sign`. As noted, `Metamask` removes access. Found the answer here: https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial.

The fix is to simply overwrite `web3` in your code. I had put web3 on the page via a script tag, which Metamask went ahead and took control over anyway. Putting it straight into a component gets past this.

```js
import Web3 from 'web3';
web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
```